# Интересный вопрос про импорт к опытным

Tags: python, tkinter, импорт, библиотека

Подскажите пожалуйста начинающему, почему при импорте модуля `tkinter` везде пишут необходимо прописывать строку: `from tkinter import *` - хотя на всех курсах учат, что импорт модуля с звездой, это ошибка и так делать нельзя, надо просто писать например: `import math` или `from math import sqrt`. Можете пояснить почему `import tkinter` не работает и вышеуказанная запись во всех материалах по обучению о нем является корректной?

Comment: "Можете пояснить почему import tkinter не работает" - вполне работает. "хотя на всех курсах учат, что импорт модуля с звездой, это ошибка и так делать нельзя" - по историческим причинам. Импорт через зведочку - это как все "игрушки" высыпать из коробки на середину комнаты. Так конечно проще делать, но лучше все-таки выбрать именно то что нужно. Я обычно использую `import tkinter as tk` и дальше к именам из этого модуля обращаюсь как `tk.Tk`, `tk.Button` и т.д.